# Laravel/Eloquent attach() method bypasses my multitenant trait

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using the Eloquent `attach()` method to insert relational data into a pivot table:

```
$this->user->roles()->attach($role, ['user_id' => $user]);
```

The above line inserts data into a pivot table linking users and their roles within my app.

The problem is that I have a trait setup to insert a `cust_id` value into the database table every time a query is executed.  The `cust_id` value never gets inserted when I use the `attach` method.  However, it works with all other methods such as `create`, `insert` etc.

My trait file:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Scopes;
use Session;

trait MultiTenantTrait
{
    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($attributes = array())
    {
        parent::__construct(array_merge($attributes, ['cust_id' => Session::get('cust_id')]));
    }

    /**
     * Append `cust_id` to all insert statements.
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function insert($attributes = array())
    {
        foreach($attributes as $key => $value) 
        {
            $attributes[$key]['cust_id'] = Session::get('cust_id');
        }

        return parent::insert($attributes);
    }

    /**
     * Boot the scope.
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public static function bootMultiTenantTrait()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new MultiTenantScope());
    }

    /**
     * Get all tenants.
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public static function allTenants()
    {
        return (new static())->newQueryWithoutScope(new MultiTenantScope());
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `insert()` method in my trait (above) is not being triggered.  Does anyone know why?

Is there a workaround?

PS - Before you ask, I have `use MultiTenantTrait` at the top of all models.

Comment: It looks like `attach` is using the query builder to insert the record into the pivot table which makes sense because the pivot table does not have it's own model.  This means there simply is no `insert` method on the model to hit because there's no model.  You may need to just set up an event handler for this particular case.

Comment: Do you think the pivot should have it's own model?

Comment: It could but in order to get this working, you'd need to manipulate the table through it's own model rather than the `attach` method (or any other methods you use which depend on that `belongsToMany` relationship).  Do you really need this to be on the pivot table though?  I don't know your business logic but it could be enough just to have this on the `users` and `roles` table?

Comment: @V4n1ll4  Try to create  a model for your pivot table and use create or insert method instead of attach, your trait should work then. I don't see why it would not work since it works with other models.

Comment: Oh, the answer is obvious, just add `cust_id` to the array of parameters you already have which currently includes `user_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've said in the comment, this isn't working because it depends on the `insert` getting hit.  The problem is the pivot table does not have its own model so there is no `insert` method.

If you need to insert `cust_id` into the pivot table, `attach` takes some additional parameters to do just that.

```
$this->user->roles()->attach($role, ['user_id' => $user, 'cust_id' => Session::get('cust_id')]);
```